# Is OSPF router ID unique per area?

Tags: router, ospf, protocol-theory

I found online that the router ID must be unique within the OSPF domain. But what exactly is an OSPF domain (an area?). Let's take the following topology:

[image]

Can R1 and R5 have the same router ID, as they are not the same area? If yes, I guess that R4's router ID has to be unique in both area 1 and 2, correct?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By the way, your drawing would never work because an OSPF area can only communicate with the backbone area (Area 0). Area 1 cannot communicate directly with Area 2.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you. That was just a quick drawing to exemplify my question, not an actual work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OSPF domain (also called an AS) is the collection of OSPF areas connected to the OSPF backbone.

*[RFC 2328, OSPF Version 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328)* defines the term, Router ID:"

```
    Router ID
        A 32-bit number assigned to each router running the OSPF
        protocol.  This number uniquely identifies the router within
        an Autonomous System.
```

-and-

```
Router ID
    A 32-bit number that uniquely identifies this router in the AS.
    One possible implementation strategy would be to use the
    smallest IP interface address belonging to the router. If a
    router's OSPF Router ID is changed, the router's OSPF software
    should be restarted before the new Router ID takes effect.  In
    this case the router should flush its self-originated LSAs from
    the routing domain (see Section 14.1) before restarting, or they
    will persist for up to MaxAge minutes.
```